# Pipeline job's builds are missing randomly in bulk

Tags: jenkins

We notice that for some reason every time that we have a successful build, and after its failure, all the builds between them deleted from the build history. 
Do you know why it is happening? Can we change it?

For example, in this attached image you can see that all the builds between 611 to 694 were deleted (we have some successes between them, but we can't see it…) 
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOKvZ.png)

We thought maybe it's coming from OpenShift, but even after disable the OCP cleanup scripts, the issue still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Check the build log retention policy in the job configuration page (Discard old builds). It could be that the logs you see are marked as **Keep this build forever** and the remaining are being purged due to the log rotation.

Comment: The 'Discard old builds' box is unchecked, means it should keep all the build forever, right?